# Return statement not working in Ajax , Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 methods here ,

```
private getAccessToken() {
    let token = this.cookie.get(this.accessTokenName);
    if (typeof token == "undefined") {
        this.rest.get('m2/token')
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.token) {
                    this.cookie.put(this.accessTokenName, response.token);
                    token = response.token;
                    return token;
                };
            });
    } else {
        return token;
    }   

}

private fetchStores() {
    const accessToken = this.getAccessToken();        
    if (!accessToken) {
        this.core.notify('Error - Fail to connect with GWA,Try again!',0);
    } else {
        this.rest.get(`m2/store/?${this.accessTokenName}=${this.getAccessToken()}`).then((stores) => console.log('stores', (stores)))
    }
}
```

when I call this method `const accessToken = this.getAccessToken();`

If token is in cookie then it works fine , but if I need to send Ajax call to get token , My accessToken is undefined show and then suddenly it throws error

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Could you please pos the full trace of the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to implement call back in your functionality. I made the changes in your methods.

```
private getAccessToken(callback) {
        let token = this.cookie.get(this.accessTokenName);
        if (typeof token == "undefined") {
            this.rest.get('m2/token')
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.token) {
                        this.cookie.put(this.accessTokenName, response.token);
                        token = response.token;
                        callback(token);
                    };
                })
        }else{
            callback(token);
        }   

    }

    private onGetAccessToken(accessToken){
       if (!accessToken) {
            this.core.notify('Error - Fail to connect with GWA,Try again!',0);
        } else {
            this.rest.get(`m2/store/?${this.accessTokenName}=${this.getAccessToken()}`)
                .then((stores) => console.log('stores', (stores)))
        }

    }
    private fetchStores() {
        this.getAccessToken(onGetAccessToken);        
    }
```